# how to use SP.BusinessData.Entity.findSpecific(identity, specificFinderName, lobSystemInstance)?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Who can help me with this function? I don't know how to use it, because i don't know what value should have the first argument "identity".

`SP.BusinessData.Entity.findSpecific(identity, specificFinderName, lobSystemInstance)`

i have `specificFinderName` and `lobSystemInstance` but not `identity`. When i try to create a new object of type EntityIdentity in this way ...

```
SP.BusinessData.Entity.findSpecific(new SP.[...].EntityIdentity(), specificFinderName, lobSystemInstance)
```

i get an error on `new SP.[...].EntityIdentity()` (args cannot be null).

When i try in this way

`SP.BusinessData.Entity.findSpecific(SP.[...].EntityIdentity.newObject(myContext), specificFinderName, lobSystemInstance)`

i get an error on `SP.[...].EntityIdentity.newObject(myContext)` (value cannot be null, parameter name : idetifierValues)

who has worked with this function of sp.js(SharePoint, JSOM), please help...

Comment: think of SP.BusinessData.Entity.findSpecific, as on 'GetByID' kind of method - in the end, without EntityIdentity it doesnt make sense. So the question is - what do you want to achieve?